# Range data annotation attribute does not validate .99?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, range, data-annotations

I have applied `Range(decimal, decimal,...)` to my property in model. It does not validate `.99`, but validates `0.99`.

How to allow the leading Zero?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in number regexp in `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.min.js` files that are by default coming with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Here is the code from `jquery.validate.js`, line 1048:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number
number: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

This function performs test of string against the number regular expression. To fix it, replace regexp with following one: `/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/`.

This is a short version. Now here is the explanation:

Buggy `^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$` regexp reads as:

```
^-?
  Beginning of line or string
  -, zero or one repetitions
Match expression but don't capture it. [\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+]
  Select from 2 alternatives
      Any digit, one or more repetitions
      \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+
          Any digit, between 1 and 3 repetitions
          Match expression but don't capture it. [,\d{3}], one or more repetitions
              ,\d{3}
                  ,
                  Any digit, exactly 3 repetitions
Match expression but don't capture it. [\.\d+], zero or one repetitions
  \.\d+
      Literal .
      Any digit, one or more repetitions
End of line or string
```

As you can see, second capturing group `(?:\.\d+)?` allows numbers in `.XX` format but when matching, first group `(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)` is checked first and validation fails because first group *must* be matched.

If we will reffer to the http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number demo and examine their regexp for number validation it will look as follows: `^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$`. Which is same as buggy one but now first matching group should be of `zero or one repetitions` or *optional* in other words. And this additional `?` in regexp fixes bug.

**Edit**: this also applies to MVC 4 default template. Both templates are using 1.9.0 version of plugin. In version 1.10.0 this issue was fixed. From [changelog](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/changelog.txt):

- Fixed regex issue for decimals without leading zeroes. Added new methods test. Fixes #41

So sometimes staying updated is a good idea.